# Override the feature of widget in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have a widget defined in knockout as shown below HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul data-bind="fastForEach: employees">
        <li class="item" data-bind="css: { 'noclose': !$parent.isCloseVisible, 'withEdit': $data.showEdit }">
            <div>
                <i data-bind="click: $parent.onClick, visible: $parent.isCloseVisible" class="itemClose"></i>
                <span class="item" data-bind="text: $data[$parent.displayText]"></span>
                <span data-bind="if: $data.showEdit" class="withEdit">
                    <i class="list"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This widget is being rendered as shown in below image.

[image]

Now there is no click event handled for **edit** icon (That is just for the display purpose). And I am not allowed to change the code of the widget.

So is there any alternate way to make this pencil icon `clickable` and handle the click event in my page ?

Comment: You're not allowed to change the code? Than how are you supposed to add new features? You'll have to add a `click: function(e) { }` data-bind to the `.withEdit` block...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can always attach a standard click handler

```
$(".withEdit").click(function () {
    var employee = ko.dataFor(this);
    // do whatever you like with the employee observable
});
```

When using knockout, i always prefer not to use jQuery like this and use the knockout approach, but since you mentioned you cannot change the existing code, this could be the option

Comment: Great answer, especially given the stipulation.